# Structuring large PHP+MySQL project

Tags: mysql, database, list, structure

I have been programming with PHP and MySQL for about a year now and I am going to have a go at my first large scale project. I am currently trying to play how I will structure the whole site database and I am running into a couple of issues to do with structure. Just for brevity I'll describe it as a social network for gamers.

So each player will have a list of favourite games, and those games will have unique properties. In this site each user in the users table will have multiple games. Im trying to figure out what is the best way to approach this:

- Is it best to store multiple games in a string that can be downloaded and parsed, and then a table of each individual games?
- Shall I have a table of users, a table of favourite games and a table of games with their attributes. And if I do it this way should I have a user as each row and then a string that could be parsed into a list, or should i have each row as 1 user and 1 game then run a search and return the rows when needed.

As you can probably tell Im just getting confused with how to handle database structures. Any and all advice would be appreciated, thank you very much for reading this.

Comment: A table for games. A table for (game) properties (or attributes). A table to link game to property. A table for users (gamer). A table for users 2 games. Never save stuff in a string that you parse - if you ever get the notion that might be a good idea, just try to imagine what someone would do to you if they inherit your project and have to go through such a mess. Having written all this, don't complicate, use the tools properly in a way that makes sense. Relational databases are about creating relations between data. Sticking stuff in a string is killing that option.

Comment: Start from designing your Entity Relationship Diagram then you'll suddenly realise that you have the answer for your own question. Just google it, you'll pick the basics up quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The second point first. You certainly know what Normalization means. If not, wiki tells us:

> Database normalization (or normalisation) is the process of organizing the columns (attributes) and tables (relations) of a relational database to minimize data redundancy.
>   [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

So, yes you should do for each, user and favourite games, a own table. And don't use a string. A better solution would be a table for user, a table for games and a table which match both together over a user-ID and a game-ID. This is the short answer. The reason why should do this fills a bunch of lectures. But to make it short, the request is faster and you will void bias towards any particular pattern of querying.

For the first point do you mean a list for the page? Or in the table itself? In both cases I would say use a database. It is, if query is good, better and in the end faster.

I hope this will help you a little bit.

Comment: This sounds good, I think my fundamental problem lies in the fact in a table you cant have a child table as in programming desktop apps I would have just used multidimensional arrays . But this helps a lot, thanks . I think I need to further my understanding of relational databases so I'm going to go and watch a bunch of youtube videos.

Comment: there are also a lot of good books...
but for the beginning database for dummies. sounds stupid i know, but there are a lot of information in it, at least in the german version, and it is easy to understand not like a few others...